# Are there any forward error correcting code algorithms for a partially reliable channel?

Tags: error-correcting-codes

There exist plenty or practical FEC algorithms - RS, Golay, convolutional codes of all sorts. All of them assume that the original data and the FEC code are sent over the same channel with the same error rate. Are there any algorithms where the size of the error correction code can be reduced, assuming that the code is sent over a separate reliable channel?

Say, we have two communication channels. One "cheap" with good throughput, but the channel can have bit errors, and the second "expensive" channel, with smaller throughput but absolutely reliable - a channel that has no bit errors of any kind. In practice, of course, two messages are sent over the same link where the first message has no error correction in place and the second message already has a rather good error correction and integrity code - so either both messages are delivered with second message integrity validated, or both messages are lost.

Most FEC algorithms assume that errors are distributed uniformly - both in original message and in ECC code and account for that. For example, Golay24 doubles the message size but operates under the assumption that error bits can happen in both original message and in Golay code. Are there any algorithms that generate shorter ECC code with assumption that it would always be transmitted correctly?